# Достать текст из Embed в в дискорде

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

пишу бота **discord.py** . У меня есть Embed и в description есть текст. Мне надо его переоброзить в обычный текст. Как это правильно сделать, пытался через ид сообщения, но ничего не получилось. Есть способ сделать это?

[image: Пример]

С этого сообщения надо достать "текст который надо перехвачивать". А вообще лучше полностью весь текст.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Может быть вам поможет [это](https://coderoad.ru/53801858/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-discord-Embedded)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.

```
msg = await channel.fetch_message(361559295071598283) # получаем сообщение
print(msg.embeds[0].description) # выводим описание первого эмбеда в сообщении
```